# Getting confusing Syntax error python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.6

Im trying to learn python and for some reason i keep getting syntax errors. When i review i See nothing wrong

OS version:

```
[root@localhost python3.6]# cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Version:

```
[root@localhost python3.6]#  python3.6 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

Python Script:
    [root@localhost python3.6]# cat ex8.py

```
formatter = "{} {} {} {}" 

print(formatter.format(1, 2, 3, 4))
print(formatter.format("one", "two", "three", "four")
print(formatter.format(True, False, False, True)) 
print(formatter.format(formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)) 
print(formatter.format(
"Bing",
"Bong", 
"Bang", 
"Bung"
))
```

Python Error:

```
[root@localhost python3.6]# python3.6 ex8.py 
  File "ex8.py", line 5
    print(formatter.format(True, False, False, True)) 
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Count your parentheses on the line before the error.

Answer (score 1):

The previous line is missing it's closing parenthesis:

```
print(formatter.format("one", "two", "three", "four"))
# This was missing ----------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thx! I guess i missed that when i was fixing other Syntax errors.